# Group by and Having aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to determine who is the largest scorer in a world cup group (this is a personal project)
I have the data but i'm having a hard time using count, group by and having in order to accomplish what i need.

[image]

I need to count messi's goals (top scorer) and group by each one of the groups so i get the highest scorer of each group.

For now i just have the joins:

```
select * from zonas
left join goles_zonas on (zonas.id = goles_zonas.Id_zona)
inner join goles on (goles.id = goles_zonas.id_gol)
inner join jugadores on (goles.id_jugador = jugadores.id)
```

Comment: You should edit the question and provide desired results.  It would also help if you put the tables in the question as *text* tables rather than images.

Comment: Image not text.  Don't identify column for group, scorer, or score.  Have not accepted a single answer.

Comment: The answer you seek can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

instead displaying all columns (by using SELECT * ), in order to group the data, I find it necessary to do SELECT only certain columns which are considered to be the keys to determine the difference of each group of dataset to get the aggregation (in this case COUNT) of each dataset group

```
SELECT Id_zona, id_gol, id_jugador, COUNT(1) as number_of_goal
FROM zonas
left join goles_zonas on (zonas.id = goles_zonas.Id_zona)
inner join goles on (goles.id = goles_zonas.id_gol)
inner join jugadores on (goles.id_jugador = jugadores.id)
GROUP BY Id_zona, id_gol, id_jugador
```

It has to be grouped by all columns included the select statement that does not being aggregated.

but if you expect to display other columns as well which are not part of the grouping keys, you can do it like this

```
SELECT goles_zonas.* , x.* FROM (
SELECT Id_zona, id_gol, id_jugador, COUNT(1) as number_of_goal
FROM zonas
left join goles_zonas on (zonas.id = goles_zonas.Id_zona)
inner join goles on (goles.id = goles_zonas.id_gol)
inner join jugadores on (goles.id_jugador = jugadores.id)
GROUP BY Id_zona, id_gol, id_jugador ) X 
LEFT JOIN goles_zonas on (x.id = goles_zonas.Id_zona)
```